# Set up jest in quasar project

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cli, quasar, jtest

I want to use jtest in order to make some unit tests, I configured according to the doc, however when I run the test I got the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlILf.png)

This is my jest.config.js file:

preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
collectCoverage: true,
coverageDirectory: './tests/report/',

transform: {
"^.+\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
".(ts|tsx)": "ts-jest",
".*\.(vue)$": '@vue/vue3-jest'
}

my babel file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ7Sb.png)

my package
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhcsT.png)

The problem the .vue file is not parsed correctly.

{{ event?.unit }}

This line is marked as error. It can understand event? ts feature?

Howevewr,i created a project using vue/cli using test + ts support and works fine, but adding jtest to quasar not work for me as expected

Any one can help me?